# Save the images of ckeditor fields to local media and not s3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, ckeditor

I'm working on a django project and I have used s3 cloud storage to save my media files. The challenge that I have faced is that I want the images of ckeditor fields to be saved on local and not s3. How should I do that?

I haven't found any solution for my problem in any community